# Change member names when using Json.Encode() to serialize object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for a way to change the name of a property when it gets encoded to JSON that works similar to the way `DisplayAttribute` can be used to change it's display name.

For example, if I encoded the following class to a JSON string

```
 public class LatLng
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

string result = Json.Encode(new LatLng{ Latitude = 10, Longitude = 20 });
```

the result would be: `{"Latitude":10,"Longitude":20}`

Is there a way to create a `JsonNameAttribute` to add to each property of the class, like below

```
 public class LatLng
{
    [JsonName("lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [JsonName("lng")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

string result = Json.Encode(new LatLng{ Latitude = 10, Longitude = 20 });
```

so the result would then be: `{"lat":10,"lng":20}`?

Can this be done without creating my own JSON serializer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities:

- Define a view model which will have the correct values and then map your `LatLng` domain model to this view model and serialize the view model.
- The [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class doesn't support attributes but you could write a custom [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx).
- Use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class which allows you to define member names by decorating them with the `[DataMember]` attribute.